# Conditionally selecting node not working

Tags: templates, xslt

I'm just trying to select the node 'productgroep' with attribute value 'cd'. This is not working and I really don't understand why, I searched for answers but didn't find any.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Oefening_8.xsl"?>
<catalogus>
<!-- cd catalogus -->
<productgroep type="cd">
    <item referentienummer="7051444" catalogusnummer="1800022" EAN="0025218000222">
     ...
</productgroep>
<productgroep type="film">
    <item referentienummer="8051445" catalogusnummer="2800023" EAN="5051888073650">
     ....
</productgroep>
</catalogus
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">   
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Oefening_8.xsl</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link href="Oefening_8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1></h1>
                <xsl:template match="productgroep[@type='cd']">
                </xsl:template>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `<xsl:template/>` cannot be a child of a `<xsl:template/>`, so your stylesheet is currently invalid and probably giving an error somewhere, depending on how you are using the XML and XSL.

One solution is to create the separate `<xsl:template>`s and use `<xsl:apply-templates />` to processes the children of the source element.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Oefening_8.xsl</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link href="Oefening_8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1></h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="productgroep[@type='cd']">
    <xsl:value-of select="item/@catalogusnummer"/> <!-- print @catalogusnummer for example -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @andyb pointed out, you can't have a template inside a template. It may be that you meant to use `xsl:apply-templates` where you have `xsl:template`, but that wouldn't have worked either with the path you used, because the current context there is the node *above* catalogus. Your options are to change the initial `xsl:template` to select the root element with either:

or

or to use the full path in the `xsl:apply-templates`:

I prefer the first option:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/*">   
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Oefening_8.xsl</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <link href="Oefening_8.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1></h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="productgroep[@type='cd']" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```